Git release flow - versions STG vs PROD
Trying to implement simple release git flow and not understand which version I need to use for PROD.
Example:
3 branches - develop, release (for staging) and master (for prod). I can`t change this, I must use these three.
Process:

Developers using develop for features, merge features back, preparing for release.

When we are ready for release, I have two options:
a) merge develop to release, create tag, ex: 1.0.0-stg
b) create new release/1.0.0 branch, create tag 1.0.0-stg (and stop to use release branch at all)
Deploy to staging and start tests process.

When BUG was found, we need to fix it.
a) For this option we create hotfix/xxx from release, fix, merge back, create 1.0.1-stg tag.
b) For option B with separate branch, it looks like... we need to create hotfix/xxx from release/1.0.0, merge back to new release/1.0.1 (from release/1.0.0) with new tag 1.0.1-stg?
After both options - merge to develop to keep changes

Finally - merge:
a) release to master and create prod tag 1.0.1-prod
b) merge release/1.0.1 to master and create prod tag 1.0.1-prod
After both options - merge to develop to keep changes


Two questions:

It looks like options A is better, you dont need to create extra branches for releases, especially when you need to bump version if you had hot fix?
Is it OK, to have for prod "first" version already with minor hotfix number - 1.0.1-prod? It is possible to create 1.0.0-prod but as for my mind it is not clear for the future - why we have 1.0.1-stg for staging and 1.0.0-prod for production and what is the difference between them. As for me it is much clearer to have same code with same versions. Am I missing something here?


“I can`t change this, I must use these three.” That’s one thing. Another thing is what all of this is for.  You say you need these three things. Then later you ask if something tangential is okay or what the point is of “stg” versus “prod”.  I don’t know because I don’t know what the purpose or meaning of it all is.
